# I have unwraped and textured my objects and i wanted to join them without messing the UV?

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to join all objects to one uv without messing up unwrap

Comment: You can use up to 8 UVMap for one mesh, just rename them differently before joining the objects.

Comment: I wanted to join the UV maps to one UV map with their texture still different

Comment: Then you have to assign different materials for those parts.